# Avoid giving prediction for input which is not trained using CNN

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I have trained 5 different hand gestures using CNN. They are working well and give the correct prediction. However, when I do a hand gesture which is other than these 5 trained gestures, the system will still categorize the hand gesture as one of the trained gesture. Meaning, the result given is wrong as the hand gesture should not be predicted. How should I overcome this issue?

I took some random pictures and categorize them as "nothing", then train them with the hand gestures to reduce the false detection. But it doesn't really help much.

Then I think maybe can use probability score to restrict the prediction, like prediction only given if the probability is more than 70%. But it doesn't work as the not-trained-gesture always get 100%.

Comment: I trained a similar cnn recently.Keeping probability score more than 95% worked for me. Also if non trained-gesture always get 100% then you need to put more data in training set. Your model is undertrained.

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Asking us how to design a loosely-defined feature is off topic.

Comment: That said, the basic problem is your model design: you trained it for exactly five classes, but then expected it to magically detect a sixth class that you hadn't defined.  Unless you built your model to cluster the inferences somehow, it won't be able to respond properly to the new situation.  As you have told us virtually *nothing* about your topology -- part of asking a complete question -- we could only guess at an answer.  Using match percentage *might* work; training examples in some "other" category *might* work.  However, as given, we have no way to give an educated response.

Comment: @Prune I didn't expect my model to magically detect a sixth class which I didn't defined. May I can explain a bit more about my model. I didn't have thumb up as my dataset for training. But then, when I am trying the system and show thumb up, the system recognize it as one of my trained gesture (V sign). This is not right and should not happen. This is the problem I would like to overcome.

Answer (score 0):

What *did* you expect to happen when you gave your model a new gesture?  You've trained it to discriminate hand gestures into one of five classes, and you have a sixth class, *nothing*, which consists of images with no hand at all.  Amending my comment above (bad counting), you now present it with an image that doesn't fit *any* of those six classes, according to your functional definition.

The problem you have is that you haven't built a viable training set.  Something with a hand will match the first five classes much more closely than the "nothing" class -- which you've likely trained to be the concept "no hand".  Therefore, you get the best match that has a hand in it, because of the many points of similarity, and very few of difference: what does the "thumb-up" gesture have in common with the "random" photos you provided?

From a standpoint of information theory, *no* model is likely to learn the differentiation you want from the provided training images.  If you want your model to learn hand gestures and discriminate them from other hand positions, then you have to train it appropriately.  Giving it a weak "other" concept isn't going to work, as you've already realized.

You will need to use a training set that includes the desired information: at least 10% of the set will have to be hand positions that are "nothing" images.  You may need more than 10%, perhaps even more than any other class.  You may need to upgrade your topology.  Experiment -- that being the usual method of model development.

Comment: I am sorry as I am a beginner for python, OpenCV and basically all the things I have done (as mentioned in the question). But I am trying to make things work by using my logic (maybe I don't have a good logical thinking as well). So hope you wont mind giving more advices to me.

Comment: So based on what I understand from your answer, it means that the system will try to categorize a gesture which is not trained to one of the trained class. The "thumb-up" gesture would be recognized as one of the 5 classes which has the most similar gesture with thumb up. It would not recognized it as "nothing" class as "nothing" consists of all "no hand" dataset. So in order to solve this problem, I should include more dataset with hands (performing gestures which are other than the 5 classes) in "nothing" class?

Comment: Or I can train variety of different hand gestures (which are other than that 5 classes) and categorize them into classes. But during the execution phase (if all the 5 classes are assigned to perform certain action), these classes would not be assigned for any action?

Comment: Right -- you train with a variety of hand gestures: your five chosen gestures, and a sixth "other gestures" class.